# Sinatra rspec capybara: "rack test requires a rack application"

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra, capybara

When running rspec to test a feature test using Sinatra Base, we are getting the following error.

This is how our feature tests looks

```
require 'capybara/rspec'

    feature 'Enter names' do
      scenario 'submitting names' do
      visit('/')
      fill_in :player_1_name, with: 'Dave'
      fill_in :player_2_name, with: 'Mittens'
      click_button 'Submit'
      expect(page).to have_content 'Dave vs. Mittens'
      end
      end
```

This is our Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
 gem 'sinatra'
 gem 'rspec-sinatra'
 gem 'capybara'
```

error:

```
 1.1) Failure/Error: visit "/"
      ArgumentError:
        rack-test requires a rack application, but none was given
      # /Users/Russell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/rack_test/driver.rb:16:in `initialize'
      # /Users/Russell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara.rb:372:in `new'
      # /Users/Russell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara.rb:372:in `block in <top (required)>'
      # /Users/Russell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/session.rb:79:in `call'
      # /Users/Russell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/session.rb:79:in `driver'
      # /Users/Russell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/session.rb:227:in `visit'
      # /Users/Russell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
      # ./spec/feature/feature_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

 1.2) Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
      ArgumentError:
        rack-test requires a rack application, but none was given
      # /Users/Russell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/rack_test/driver.rb:16:in `initialize'
      # /Users/Russell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara.rb:372:in `new'
      # /Users/Russell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara.rb:372:in `block in <top (required)>'
      # /Users/Russell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/session.rb:79:in `call'
      # /Users/Russell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/session.rb:79:in `driver'
      # /Users/Russell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/session.rb:103:in `reset!'
      # /Users/Russell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara.rb:257:in `block in reset_sessions!'
      # /Users/Russell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara.rb:257:in `each'
      # /Users/Russell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara.rb:257:in `reset_sessions!'
      # /Users/Russell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/rspec.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

We've tried requiring the spec_helper file in our feature test, and also requiring our app.rb in the feature test and we get a different error saying it cannot load sinatra-base

```
Here is our spec_helper 

ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'

require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'app.rb')

require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'rspec'

Capybara.app = Battle

RSpec.configure do |config|
config.include Capybara::DSL

config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
end

config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|

mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
end


end
```

Any direction would be massively appreciated.

Thanks

Russ

Comment: Are you creating your own session? and if so did you pass your app to it -`Capybara::Session.new(:rack_test, Battle)`  - Capybara.app is only used if you're letting Capybara manage the sessions

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here:
http://recipes.sinatrarb.com/p/testing/rspec

It suggests, among other things, adding the following to your `spec_helper.rb`:

```
module RSpecMixin
 include Rack::Test::Methods
 def app() Sinatra::Application end
end

RSpec.configure do |config| 
  config.include RSpecMixin 
end
```